# Access a variable from setup_method in pytest

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I am quiet new to pytest.
I have declared my Testclass as follows

```
class TestSerialPort():

  @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
  def setupandtear(self,request):
     obj = connect_serialport()
     yield
     obj.close()

  def test_abc(self,setupandtear)
   print ("object {}".format(obj.port))
```

I am seeing issue while accessing obj in test method. How can I access "obj" from setup to test_abc?

Comment: try `yield obj` in your fixture - one of core pytest devs

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it , can you please elaborate it? Thanks

Comment: Can I also get to know that is it possible to use "obj" from setupandtear in test_abc() without passing "setupandtear" as an argument to test_abc? In other words, I would like to use obj as a global variable in all test method

Comment: you could have a class scoped fixture and assign to `self.` -- but the way you have it written now is the pytest-way to do things